# Is it possible to determine whether parameters are present in request JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I have an `action` table in my database, therefore I have `Action` entity and `ActionDTO` which are basically the same.

Entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "action")
public class Action {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date endDate;

    //setters & getters
}
```

DTO is:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ActionDTO {
    private String name;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

    //setters & getters
}
```

In controller there's a method to update `action` table:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/action", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateAction(@RequestBody ActionDTO actionDTO) {
    Action action = new Action();

    // setting parameters to Action entity

    actionRepository.save(action);
}
```

Depending on the presence or absence of fields `startDate` and `endDate` in request payload I need to determine whether I should update `start_date` and `end_date` in my database.

So if request JSON is:

```
{
    "name" : "action name",
    "startDate" : null,
    "endDate" : null
}
```

then I **should** update`start_date` and `end_date` fields as NULL.

But if request JSON is:

```
{
    "name" : "action name"
}
```

then I **should not** update `start_date` and `end_date` and leave them intact.

So is it possible to determine whether parameters `startDate` and `endDate` were present in HTTP request? Perhaps Jackson offers some solution out of the box?

Comment: This is _not_ how the PUT operation should work. PUTting data should always update all fields. A missing field in JSON is _equivalent_ to having the field set to `null`. In that case the PUT operation should update the database so that the result is also `null` (in those fields). You are asking how to update only a part of the object. For this, the PATCH operation exists, for which the JSON representation looks similar but different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ObjectMapper`'s terms, a missing field and a field set to `null` are identical. So, by deserialising a `String` into a `POJO`, you won't be able to see if a field existed or not. However, if that's what you want to do then you can try deserialising the json into `Map`, e.g.:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/action", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateAction(@RequestBody Map payload) {
    if(payload.containsKey("")) {
        //Something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ObjectMapper.readTree](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.lang.String)) to read the tree of `JsonNode` objects and then use [JsonNode.has](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#has(java.lang.String)) method to check whether field is present in node or not:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/action", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateAction(@RequestBody String json) {
    Action action = new Action();
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
    if (jsonNode.has("startDate")) {
        // fill action object
    }

    actionRepository.save(action);
}
```